# Perl module hierarchy and build requirement

Tags: perl, dependencies, perl-module, cpan

If have a Module that depends on [Unicode::GCString](https://metacpan.org/module/Unicode%3a%3aGCString) and [Text::LineFold](https://metacpan.org/module/Text%3a%3aLineFold) - both are in [Unicode::LineBreak](https://metacpan.org/module/Unicode%3a%3aLineBreak). Should I put [Unicode::GCString](https://metacpan.org/module/Unicode%3a%3aGCString) and [Text::LineFold](https://metacpan.org/module/Text%3a%3aLineFold) as `requires` in the `Build.PL` file or simply [Unicode::LineBreak](https://metacpan.org/module/Unicode%3a%3aLineBreak)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Include the modules you directly use.

If the module is broken out into its own distribution, the dependency tracker can then find the updated location.  It is up to the module distribution tools to generate the appropriate information in META.* to identify what modules are contained in what distributions.

If you do not point to the module that you directly use, the dependency tracker will still pull in the distribution that the module was originally contained within, not the current distribution that it is contained within.

This can be potentially challenging if your application dynamically loads one-of a set of modules, but in general, this is the approach I use.

See the history of [LWP::Protocol::https](https://github.com/libwww-perl/lwp-protocol-https/tree/6.02) as an example of this happening.